# How to sum the Distance column in df1 based on the date_time rows from dataframe df using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Data Frames  df and df1,  based on the date range from df i want to sum the Distance column in df1

```
from io import StringIO
data = """IGN,External,Voltage,date_time
0,ON,53.06,13-11-2023 10:01:14
743,ON,47.80,13-11-2023 15:42:11
745,ON,51.20,13-11-2023 16:22:41
1152,ON,50.44,13-11-2023 19:18:26
1155,ON,52.88,14-11-2023 09:39:54
2191,ON,53.66,14-11-2023 14:45:53
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=['date_time'], dayfirst=True)
data1 = """IGN,External,Distance,date_time
0,ON,1,13-11-2023 10:01:14
300,ON,5,13-11-2023 10:42:11
400,ON,6,13-11-2023 11:42:11
743,ON,9,13-11-2023 15:42:11
745,ON,10,13-11-2023 16:22:41
1000,ON,12,13-11-2023 17:13:43
1152,ON,89,13-11-2023 19:18:26
1155,ON,52.88,14-11-2023 09:39:54
1189,ON,54.33,14-11-2023 10:39:54
2191,ON,34,14-11-2023 14:45:53
"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1), parse_dates=['date_time'], dayfirst=True)
```

based on the df I want to sum the Distance for df1
expected output is
actually below data is manually generated output

```
           start_date            end_date  Distance
0 2023-11-13 10:01:14 2023-11-13 15:42:11     21.00
1 2023-11-13 16:22:41 2023-11-13 19:18:26    111.00
2 2023-11-14 09:39:54 2023-11-14 14:45:53    141.21
```

Comment: what is the logic? Why are you splitting at `2023-11-13 16:22:41` and `2023-11-14 09:39:54`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of `mozway` is already satisfying, but this is another method.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


def get_df(data):
    return pd.read_csv(
        StringIO(data), parse_dates=["date_time"], dayfirst=True
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df1 = get_df(
        """IGN,External,Voltage,date_time
        0,ON,53.06,13-11-2023 10:01:14
        743,ON,47.80,13-11-2023 15:42:11
        745,ON,51.20,13-11-2023 16:22:41
        1152,ON,50.44,13-11-2023 19:18:26
        1155,ON,52.88,14-11-2023 09:39:54
        2191,ON,53.66,14-11-2023 14:45:53
        """
    )
    df2 = get_df(
        """IGN,External,Distance,date_time
        0,ON,1,13-11-2023 10:01:14
        300,ON,5,13-11-2023 10:42:11
        400,ON,6,13-11-2023 11:42:11
        743,ON,9,13-11-2023 15:42:11
        745,ON,10,13-11-2023 16:22:41
        1000,ON,12,13-11-2023 17:13:43
        1152,ON,89,13-11-2023 19:18:26
        1155,ON,52.88,14-11-2023 09:39:54
        1189,ON,54.33,14-11-2023 10:39:54
        2191,ON,34,14-11-2023 14:45:53
        """
    )

    group_times = zip(df1.date_time[:-1:2], df1.date_time[1::2])
    new_df = []
    for start_date, stop_date in group_times:
        new_df.append(
            {
                "start_date": start_date,
                "stop_date": stop_date,
                "distance": df2[
                    (start_date <= df2.date_time)
                    & (df2.date_time <= stop_date)
                ].Distance.sum(),
            }
        )
    result = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
    print(result)

    
    # OR:
    result = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            {
                "start_date": s1,
                "stop_date": s2,
                "distance": df2[
                    (s1 <= df2.date_time) & (df2.date_time <= s2)
                ].Distance.sum(),
            }
            for s1, s2 in zip(df1.date_time[:-1:2], df1.date_time[1::2])
        ]
    )
```

|  | start_date | stop_date | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-11-13 10:01:14 | 2023-11-13 15:42:11 | 21 |
| 1 | 2023-11-13 16:22:41 | 2023-11-13 19:18:26 | 111 |
| 2 | 2023-11-14 09:39:54 | 2023-11-14 14:45:53 | 141.21 |

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to aggregate on the ranges of values that start and end on pairs of values from `df`, you could [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to identify those, then craft a grouper and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
tmp = df1.merge(df, on='date_time', how='left').sort_values(by='date_time')
s = tmp['Voltage'].notna()
out = (df1.groupby((s&s.shift(fill_value=True)).cumsum())
          .agg(**{'start_date': ('date_time', 'min'),
                  'end_date': ('date_time', 'max'),
                  'Distance': ('Distance', 'sum')
                 })
          .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
           start_date            end_date  Distance
0 2023-11-13 10:01:14 2023-11-13 15:42:11     21.00
1 2023-11-13 16:22:41 2023-11-13 19:18:26    111.00
2 2023-11-14 09:39:54 2023-11-14 14:45:53    141.21
```

Intermediate:

```
   IGN_x External_x  Distance           date_time   IGN_y External_y  Voltage      s  grouper
0      0         ON      1.00 2023-11-13 10:01:14     0.0         ON    53.06   True        1
1    300         ON      5.00 2023-11-13 10:42:11     NaN        NaN      NaN  False        1
2    400         ON      6.00 2023-11-13 11:42:11     NaN        NaN      NaN  False        1
3    743         ON      9.00 2023-11-13 15:42:11   743.0         ON    47.80   True        1
4    745         ON     10.00 2023-11-13 16:22:41   745.0         ON    51.20   True        2
5   1000         ON     12.00 2023-11-13 17:13:43     NaN        NaN      NaN  False        2
6   1152         ON     89.00 2023-11-13 19:18:26  1152.0         ON    50.44   True        2
7   1155         ON     52.88 2023-11-14 09:39:54  1155.0         ON    52.88   True        3
8   1189         ON     54.33 2023-11-14 10:39:54     NaN        NaN      NaN  False        3
9   2191         ON     34.00 2023-11-14 14:45:53  2191.0         ON    53.66   True        3
```

Comment: @appu was there an issue with my answer?